# Introduction of extra line in the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a figure as shown below, and I would like to add a straight line of green color between red and blue curves but not between blue and red(if we see from left to right direction)
[image]

This is my MWE, which gives above figure,

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
{\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick,red]{G-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a sketch of how the result should look like?

Comment: sorry, your mwe doesn't work. can you show original source of your code?

Comment: I guess you may want to comment out the line `\wire[thick,green]{R-\i}` to make your MWE working.

Comment: @samcarter corrected, Zarko and marmot. My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
{\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick,red]{R-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,green]{G-\i}{{\i*\pairdist-0.5*\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{0}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @Shamina I updated my answer accordingly.